# Send Email to Gmail with Batch File Using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, email, batch-file

I am trying to send an email to gmail using a batch file and I get this:

```
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server
response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
At line:1 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -port 25 -UseSsl -Credent ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Something with authetication. I put get credentials in there though.

Batch File Code:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage 
-SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -port 25 -UseSsl 
-Credential (Get-Credential) 
-To ansorensen1118@gmail.com 
-From ansorensen1118@gmail.com 
-Subject Testing 
-Body 123
```

Comment: ?, I only have 1 reputation. I would put it here if I could.

Comment: Has nothing to do with reputation.  It is much easier to copy and paste text into your question then it is to take a screenshot and use that in your question.

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense. I will.

Comment: Per [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) the outgoing ports are 465 or 587.

Comment: @Squashman Still the same error.

Comment: I guess you don't need to use the port.  This is what worked for me: `Send-MailMessage -To me@domain.com -From you@domain.com  -Subject Testing -Body Testing -Credential (Get-Credential) -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -UseSsl`

Comment: Can you give me the the whole thing you used. Was it in powershell? It still doesn't work. When it asks for credentials do you put Windows or Gmail credentials?

Comment: That's powershell; give it the gmail credentials

Comment: How do I put spaces in the body? It just gives an error if I do. Double quotes don't work.

Comment: Does you batch file really have all the line-breaks as you have her in your post?

Comment: No, I changed it to just one line of commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very clear now. You do not need a port, it is optional. Under User Name put your email address and under password put your email password.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential) -To ansorensen1118@gmail.com -From ansorensen1118@gmail.com -Subject Testing -Body 123
```